# Hibernate left join returns objects

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm doing a query which returns objects in stead of a custom class:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("FROM Author a LEFT JOIN a.documents d LEFT JOIN d.personDocuments pd WHERE pd.person = :person ORDER BY a.lastName");
q.setParameter("person", person);
return new HashSet<Author>(q.getResultList());
```

I would expect that q.getResultList() would return a list of Authors (and their linked documents), however it's a list of objects. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `getResultList()` from [Query](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList%28%29) is not typed.
Therefore it seems that it only returns `Objects` (which really are instances of `Author` in your case), which you manually have to cast to `Author`. (You can check what the `Object` really is by inspecting `getClass()` on an instance for example.)

You can use [TypedQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html) for typed queries, which will work as you need them.

```
TypedQuery<Author> q = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Author a LEFT JOIN a.documents d LEFT JOIN d.personDocuments pd WHERE pd.person = :person ORDER BY a.lastName", Author.class);
q.setParameter("person", person);
return new HashSet<Author>(q.getResultList());
```

This [Tutorial](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/execute) from objectdb covers it quite well.

Comment: I think "It will return Objects" is misleading. It is returning Authors but there is no typed variable to access them and no guarantee by the method's signature to do so.

Comment: @his that's what I meant :D I'll try to rephrase and make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but still not quite there yet:   `TypedQuery<Author> q = em.createQuery("FROM Author a LEFT JOIN a.documents d LEFT JOIN d.personDocuments pd WHERE pd.person = :person ORDER BY a.lastName", Author.class);` gives me: `Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type`

Comment: @user485659 add SELECT a to the beginning of the query